# Discord bot not responding made using discord.js module

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am very new to discord bots and I tried a lot to create the simplest bot but until now I got a bot which gets online once I run the code but except that it doesn't do anything. Here is the code for it:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();


const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
]});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});
  
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

client.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log("I see a message");
    if (msg.content === 'Hello') msg.reply('Hi');
});
```

I don't know what is the problem. I enter the message in the server but this bot is not responding. Please someone help me out with this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

***message*** is deprecated you need to use ***messageCreate***

// More info about this: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate

// Also place the login all the way to the bottom

```
client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
  console.log("I see a message");
  if (msg.content === 'Hello') msg.reply('Hi');
});
        
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is really useful. I can finally see the desired results now.